# how to add radio group

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, radio-group

[image]I had made an Activity page in android with table of size 12*5. In this table i have 20 radio buttons vertically aligned.but  now i need to add radio group in this table ..how can i make it possible .

my XML code  is as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.dassd.androidapp.Activity8">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_marginRight="138dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="138dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Sr.no" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Name" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Gender" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Age (in years" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="male" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="female" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="1" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>


        <RadioButton

            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable" />

        <RadioButton

            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:checked="false" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="29"></RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="2" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="3" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton5"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText12"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="4" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton7"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText16"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="5" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText17"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton9"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton10"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText20"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="6" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton11"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton12"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText24"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="7" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText25"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton13"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton14"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText28"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>


</TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="8" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText29"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton15"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton16"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText32"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>


</TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="9" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText33"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton17"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton18"
            android:checked="false" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText36"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        </EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="10" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText37"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton19"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton20"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText40"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
</TableRow>


</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Could you please tell me the names and ages of all members in the age group of 8-34 years? Please start from the youngest member. Also tell me their gender "
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="764dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="764dp" />
```

[image]

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Replace with this

Comment: added those code to button 19&20. but while running it shows " unfortunately app has stopped".

Comment: can you post log for the crash?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference

Comment: Have you used visibility in java code
Once Clean project and run

Comment: nope.. i didn't made any java codes its simply left blank... only i made is design in XML

Comment: Then the NullPointerException leads to which line please check that

Answer (score 0):

This code worked..

```
<RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width=".5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/radioButton19"
                android:checked="false" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width=".5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/radioButton20"
                android:checked="false" />
        </RadioGroup>
```